# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page on a submenu

Tags: plugin-development, capabilities, permissions

I'm writing my first plugin for WordPress and am running into a permission issue when trying to pass a parameter to a page.

I've added a submenu page to process a delete for a category from the database when the user navigates to the link.

However, when you navigate to the specific URL, I am getting the error:

> You do not have sufficient privileges to access this page.

Here is the adding of the submenu page:

```
add_submenu_page( null, 'Delete Category', 'Delete Category', 'administrator', 'ecosystem-delete-category );
```

All of the categories have a `Delete` link next to them and when the user clicks on the link for a category they are redirected to the url with the passed in `ID` parameter.

```
echo '<td><a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ecosystem-delete-category?id=' . $categoryId . '">Delete</a></td>'
```

And then this is what I have on my `ecosystem-delete-category` page:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ecosys_category";
$wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'category_ID' => $id) );
```

I believe my issue is with passing the parameter but maybe I'm wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're adding a submenu page with no menupage at all - a `null` parameter!!

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Yes, that is intentional. I do not want to display the submenu page in the actual submenu. So by passing `null`, it essentially "hides" it from the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued to do more research and ended up finding the solution to my problem! Since the url I am passing the parameter to is `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ecosystem-delete`. I didn't even notice that `?page=ecosystem-delete` is already a parameter, so I needed to pass my second parameter into the URL as `&id=` rather than `?id=`.

A simple overlooked mistake. :)